The tensor product of matrix subalgebras.
Let $N$ be a separable $II_{1}$ factor. I usually used the conclusion that if $M_{n}$ is matrix subalgebra of $N$, then $N={M_{n}}\otimes{(M_{n}^{\prime} \cap N)} $. But I don't know the details of the proof. Thanks a lot.

Hint: Prove that $N = M_n \otimes e_{11}Ne_{11}$, then show that $M_n’ \cap N = I_n \otimes e_{11}Ne_{11} \simeq e_{11}Ne_{11}$.

Thanks for your help. I understand your perfect idea.
